# Why do the profiles say seen IN x hours?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-profiles

Can you predict the future?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity bugs for "seen" and "visited" in profile](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31/activity-bugs-for-seen-and-visited-in-profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come back in a bit, it will be fixed. All it takes is time.

More seriously, there was a slight error on migration of users from WebApps to Meta.  It has been fixed, but the incorrect access times linger.  Obviously, they will be replaced as you use the site.